Forced factors of numbers like $100001000110002\cdots 10447$?
In an old factoring project I currently attack again I dealt with positive integers that emerge if one writes down the numbers $10\ 000$ to some number $k$ with $10\ 000\le k\le 99\ 999$ in increasing order. The generating term is $$\frac{10^{5n+5}\cdot 999990001-99999\cdot n-1000090000}{9999800001}$$ when we end with the number $k:=10^4+n$

I found no prime of this form with at most $80\ 000$ digits and noticed that many of those numbers have several large prime factors. Therefore I wonder whether there are any forced factors (algebraic , aurifieuillan or whatsoever) showing that all those numbers must be composite or whether it was just "bad luck" so far and there might still be a prime of this form waiting to be discovered.


Do you care specifically starting at $10^n$? Because if you start at $10^n + k$ then you can absolutely get primes

What's special about $10000$?  There has been lots of effort to find a prime in the sequence $1, 12, 123, \ldots$: see OEIS sequence A007908, with none found yet although it is conjectured that there should be such primes.  I would guess your search would be similar.

@Snared Yes , I only considered numbers beginning with "$10000$".

@RobertIsrael The several large prime factors could indicate some hidden forced factors , but this can of course also be an illusion.

See also A341715.

Really , those numbers are on OEIS ? This is a huge surprise.

If you start at $49$, the first prime you get is $495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118119120121122123124125126127128129130131132133134135136137138139140141142143144145146147148149150151152153154155156157158159160161162163164165166167168169170171172173174175176177178179180181182183184185186187188189190191192193194195196197198199200201202203204205206207208209210211212213214215216217218219220221222223224225226227228229230231232233234235236237238239240241$.

For example, $10006...10033$ is prime (I know it isn't starting at $10^k$, but..)

Likewise $1001010011$ is prime

So not finding anything in the first $80000$ digits is no indication there won't be a prime eventually. But it could be a very long search.

I'm surprised how quickly isprime from the sympy package works out of the box. I was able to check every value of 6000 digits or fewer in just 7 minutes. Now it's up to 10000...11328 after just 9m. You claim to have checked up to 10000...26000, to be clear? How long did that take you? I'm curious how much progress I would make if I left it running overnight, not to mention running it on multiple machines or after overclocking.

progress has considerably slowed down though. After running for 30 minutes it only reaches 10000...11892, which has roughly 10,000 digits. So how could you have possibly checked all of 20,000 or fewer digits? You must have run this on a supercomputer for hundreds of hours?

80,000 I mean instead of 20,000...

The reason for the fast progress is that many of those numbers have small prime factors.

How long did it take you to calculate the first 80,000 digit primalities, roughly? Is there some kind of trick you used, or you ran brute force on a proprietary "is_prime" map?

@Snared, when using python the library gmpy2 is much faster. I checked the primality of 10000...14000 using the gmpy2.is_prime() function within 4 minutes. In general, the sympy library contains a lot of functions, but the majority are written in python, which causes a slow runtime.

@jorisperrenet all of that is minor speedups - Even using gmpy2, isprime(10000...26011) takes multiple minutes on my machine. And the theorem would require isprime(10000...99999) where each increment by 2 adds 10 DIGITS to your number. Switching to gmpy2 won't help in any meaningful way but I appreciate the suggestion.

I have checked all numbers up to 10000...33360 and found no primes.
